# What to do whenever I opens my browser it shows "ORACLE DATABASE 10g EXPRESS EDITION LICENSE AGREEMENT"?

Tags: oracle, google-chrome, firefox, mozilla

None  of my browser are working whenever I query in browser I get the message "ORACLE DATABASE 10g EXPRESS EDITION LICENSE AGREEMENT". What to do?

Comment: And have you installed Oracle XE database?

Comment: No I have not installed it.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced same issue and fixed the issue by following these steps. Please have a try.

From Start | Run open a command window. Assuming your environmental variables are set correctly start with the following:

```
C:\>sqlplus /nolog
SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Tue Aug 26 10:40:44 2008
Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> connect
Enter user-name: system
Enter password: <enter password if will not be visible>
Connected.
SQL> Exec DBMS_XDB.SETHTTPPORT(3010); [Assuming you want to have HTTP going to this port]   

 PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>quit
```

Now restart the PC and check.